# Why height text box is less than button?

Tags: css

Why height text box is less than button?

My Code :

```css
 #container {
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.t,#but {
   float: left;
}
#but ,.txt {
   border: 1px solid #999;
   padding: 10px; 
   font-size: 20px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="t">
 <input type="text" class="txt" name="">
 </div>
 <div id="but"><span>Search</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because of the `font-size` not getting added. try giving same font-size to all the elements there you are using. it would work.

Comment: Font size is 13.333px by default. Increase it to 14px and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<input>` element, is one of the replaced elements, and In CSS, a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) is an element whose representation is outside the scope of CSS. It has some special styles from browser user agent stylesheet, and they don't get inherited by default, such as `font-family`, `font-size`, `line-height` etc., and those rules can determine a box's height.

You can force them to get inherited by setting `<property>: inherit;`, so that the `<input type="text">` can inherit those styles from `<div class="t">` and its parent `<div id="container">` etc., so it will be able to get the same style as the `<div id="but">`, in order to make them the same height.

You can set those specific styles on the input box directly, but using inherit can prevent from overriding rules.

```css
#container {
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.t,
#but {
  float: left;
}

.txt {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.txt,
#but {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="t">
    <input type="text" class="txt" name="">
  </div>
  <div id="but"><span>Search</span></div>
</div>
```

In addition, you will use a `<button>` tag instead of `<div>` button in the real case I think. To make the input field and button the same height, you will also need to set the same `padding` values for them directly.

```css
#container {
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.t,
#but {
  float: left;
}

.txt,
#but {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="t">
    <input type="text" class="txt" name="">
  </div>
  <button id="but"><span>Search</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser handles difference html element and attribute differently i check it computed tab in chrome developer tool and find out input field render height differently 1 px more in top and bottom so its 2 px actual height you set.

these line will fix your problem, check the snippet for how to apply them.

```
font-size:16px;
line-height:16px;
height:16px;  
font-family:sans-serif;
```

```css
#container {
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.t,#but {
   float: left;
}
#but ,.txt {
   border: 1px solid #999;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size:16px;
   line-height:16px;
   height:16px;
   font-family:sans-serif;
   
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="t">
 <input type="text" class="txt" name="" placeholder="write a name" />
 </div>
 <div id="but"><span>Search</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

/*You'll need to do something like this although there is likely to be some differences across systems.*/

```css
.searchtext {
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-right:none;
    padding:4px;
    margin:0px;
    float:left;
    height:16px;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:16px;
}
.searchbutton {
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#fd0;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:4px;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    height:26px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:5em;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `font-size` to all your elements, they will become of equal `height`.

```css
#container {
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.t,
#but {
  float: left;
}

#but,
.txt {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="t">
    <input type="text" class="txt" name="">
  </div>
  <div id="but"><span>Search</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but if font-size is more then the scenario is going opposite

Comment: @SahilDhir it will. so in such scenario's give a fixed `height` to your elements.

Comment: but why its happening I need to know the cause

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is your `font-size`.

Please try to give `font-size` to all your elements like in the following fiddle:

```css
#container {
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.t,
#but {
  float: left;
}

#but,
.txt {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="t">
    <input type="text" class="txt" name="">
  </div>
  <div id="but"><span>Search</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid selector:

```
line-height: 100%;
```

You have to define height to container, or wrap your inner content with:

```
.container .wrap{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And then set height: 100% to your #but element.